# I try to use a variable from a function with tkinter and got NameError: name 'hastag_lbl' is not defined

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

```
File "test_gui.py", line 43, in browseFiles_hstg
hastag_lbl.configure(text = filename)
NameError: name 'hastag_lbl' is not defined
```

I Try to call this variable put its say its not defined I try with globals also didn`t help.How can I set hastag_lbl to be accesable by the program.

```
def browseFiles_hstg(): 
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", 
                                      title = "Select a File", 
                                      filetypes = (("Text files", 
                                                    "*.txt*"), 
                                                   ("all files", 
                                                    "*.*"))) 
     # Change label contents 
     hastag_lbl.configure(text = filename)

def start_hashtag():
    with open(hastag_lbl.cget('text'), 'r') as file:
         data = [line.strip() for line in file]


class Hashtag_page(tk.Frame):
    def  __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        hastag_lbl = tk.Label(self, text='Choice file with hashtags').pack(side='top',fill='x',pady=10)
        tk.Button(self, text='Browse files', command=browseFiles_hstg).pack()
        tk.Label(self, text='Enter how much likes, follows action per hastag').pack()
        amount = tk.Entry(self).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='Start Bot', command=start_hashtag).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='Back', command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageOne)).pack()
```

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.  Your posted code fails on syntax errors.  If we fix the indentation, all it does is to define two functions and a class -- then it quits without executing anything.

Comment: Excellent! I see you have an Error Traceback and you have improved the indentation of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hastag_lbl` is not defined in your function. Did you mean to pass it in as a parameter?

```py
def browseFiles_hstg(hastag_lbl): 
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", 
                                      title = "Select a File", 
                                      filetypes = (("Text files", 
                                                    "*.txt*"), 
                                                   ("all files", 
                                                    "*.*"))) 
    # Change label contents 
    hastag_lbl.configure(text = filename)

class Hashtag_page(tk.Frame):

    def  __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        hastag_lbl = tk.Label(self, text='Choice file with hashtags').pack(side='top',fill='x',pady=10)
        tk.Button(self, text='Browse files', command=lambda : browseFiles_hstg(hastag_lbl)).pack()
```

Comment: Yes I want to use it in start_hashtag() function

Comment: You can use the same procedure to pass the `Label` into that function as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use globals to do this if you want, but ideally you would use instance variables and keep everything in one class.

```
class Hashtag_page(tk.Frame):
    def  __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        # note using 2 lines here, very important!
        self.hastag_lbl = tk.Label(self, text='Choice file with hashtags')
        self.hastag_lbl.pack(side='top',fill='x',pady=10)
        tk.Button(self, text='Browse files', command=self.browseFiles_hstg).pack()
        tk.Label(self, text='Enter how much likes, follows action per hastag').pack()
        amount = tk.Entry(self)
        amount.pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='Start Bot', command=self.start_hashtag).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='Back', command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageOne)).pack()

    def browseFiles_hstg(self): 
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", 
                                          title = "Select a File", 
                                          filetypes = (("Text files", 
                                                        "*.txt*"), 
                                                       ("all files", 
                                                        "*.*"))) 
         # Change label contents 
         self.hastag_lbl.configure(text = filename)
    
    def start_hashtag(self):
        with open(self.hastag_lbl.cget('text'), 'r') as file:
             data = [line.strip() for line in file]
```

Comment: Thank you that its the sulutin.

Comment: I have another issue now variable from another class and pass it into start_hashtag function.And I get a AttributeError: 'Hashtag_page' object has no attribute 'username.Any sugestion how to iheritate that variable.'When I Inheritance the hole class give me an eror something for tkinter